# Training a neural network when order of indices in target label is meaningless, abitrary

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to train an NN to approximate some coordinates from some 2d data - a matrix for a conv net and a long vector for a traditional NN.

So the network takes the data as input, outputs 6 floats and tries to learn from labels, x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3 by minimizing mean squared error.

**The issue is that the ordering of the points in the label is meaningless. x1,y1 could just as easily be x3,y3 or vice versa. Nothing in the input data distinguishes one point from any other besides its position.**

but, the network when by minimizing sum((approximation - target)^2)/6 assumes that order does matter so that even if the network guessed for ex: .42,.23 when there was a point at .44,.22, the cost function might be very high if it guessed the point in indices 0 and 1 when .44,.22 was in indices 2 and 3 in the target label. As is, the network cannot learn because it has no way of learning which point should go first, second, third, for any given training sample, even if the network does learn the function that maps the input data to the a pair of coordinates.

Are there any elegant solutions to this problem?

I have tried artificially ordering the points, such that points are sorted by x value. (x1 is always the smallest and x3 is always the largest). This helps, but it is not ideal as the network then has to learn an additional function on top of finding the coordinates of these points.

Please don't tell me to just use other methods, I am, but i would like to explore how these other methods stack up against dnns.

thank you!

Comment: what did you do so-far?any code or errors?

Comment: Voted to close: this question is more appropriate for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) rather than Stack Overflow. You should take it over there for a solution, and ask any questions here if you run into a problem coding that solution.

Comment: There are no errors. The code runs, but there is a bug -- not necessarily related to statistics -- as i described above. I have tried artificially ordering the points, as described above, and this helps MSE converge to something considerably more reasonable. That said I do not think my solution is ideal -- I am hoping that there might be a better solution.

Comment: But what exactly your network should learn on top of these predictions? In this case - if you want to train yet another network on top of existing one you should also take into account that new input would be ordering insensitive.

Comment: I think this is a researchy question. Have you read http://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06391v4.pdf ?

Comment: Thank you @AlexandrePassos! This is helpful